# Two title pages, one with author names and one without?

Tags: titles, titling

I need to submit a report with two title pages - the first with paper title and authors, and the second with just the title, no author names.  I used the `titling` package which lets me have two title pages, but the second title page is the same as the first.  Is there a package or something that'll let me do what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  It would be helpful (and you will get more positive response) if you could include a minimum working example that shows what you have so far and illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the two titles in two separate `titlepage`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

% First title page
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \vskip 60pt
  \LARGE This is the report title \par
  \vskip 3em
  \large Author A, Author B \par
  \vskip 1.5em
  \today
\end{titlepage}

% Second title page
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \vskip 60pt
  \LARGE This is the report title \par
  \vskip 3em
  \large %Author A, Author B \par
  %\vskip 1.5em
  \today
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

The above definitions (skips and font sizes) were taken partially from [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls).

There's no need to specifically rely on `\maketitle` or what happens to the contents when using macros `\title`, `\author` and/or `\date`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really necessary you use any titling-package. Take a look on the [manual (pdf)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf) from the `titlepages`-package: There you can find a lot of examples for titlepages which are created as 'normal' text. You have to do it manually, but therefor you really get, what you want.

Margins you can adjust (if needed) with the `geometry`-package.

Answer (score 1):

The `\author` command is reusable when you use the `titling` package, so you can write `\author{}` between the two title pages to clear the author field.