Need to add another title before \begin{document} on a separate page
I am a complete beginner. I need to add another title similar to the \title but on a different page right after it. I'd appreciate it very much if anyone could me as I urgently need this.
Thanks in advance!

There is the {titlepage} environment, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169421/82917

Because of the missing minimal working example only a guess: There are classes like the KOMA-Script and package like uni-titlepage, that support more than one title page with \maketitle. The extended KOMA-Script title pages are also available for, e.g., the standard classes using package scrextend.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable Tex code you have so far! then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

The titling package also supports multiple \maketitles if you're using a standard class. But if you need this urgently, create an extra page as a separate document and use pdfpages \includepdf{<filename>} after \begin{document}. You cannot add anything before \begin{document} which results in any output at all.

hey everyone, thank you so much for everyone's response. the {titlepage} environment did the job for me. y'all rock!
